# How to target the year in this date string 01/01/2004

Tags: mysql, date

I have a database of users and the date of birth stored in the database is in this format 01/01/2004. I have read that I should have the year first. So how would I target the year in this string. I want to do the following.

```
UPDATE users 
SET level = 9 
WHERE birthyear = 2003
```

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't you first convert your dates and then change the column type to DATE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the name of your field is birthdate (and not birthyear), then the following will work.  The `YEAR` function will return the year for a given `date` or `datetime` field.

```
UPDATE users SET level = 9 WHERE YEAR(birthdate) = 2003;
```

If the date is stored in a string data type (bad idea), with the format you specified, the following would work.  The `RIGHT` function takes the last n characters of a given string.

```
UPDATE users SET level = 9 WHERE RIGHT(birthdate, 4) = 2003;
```

Comment: The second part is not Y10k compatible ;-)

Comment: Amazingly quick, correct response and very informative. I will change the date next time. Cheers

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.  It's always easier to work with dates when they are stored in `DATE` or `DATETIME` data types.